# image slide, with div outside of container with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, slideshow

so i have an issue, with an image slider i am trying to build..

[image: Example image of what i want to achieve.]

above is what i roughly want to achieve.

i have the grey box, which is my wrapper, inside of that, i have a smaller boxes with images, that should not be shown outside of the wrapper as shown on the image.

but the images will have a small button on it, which should expand a div, with info on.

how can i achieve this ?

the expanded div, should also follow the div it belongs to when sliding the image slider..

i have a simple markup so far, but i am unable to produce the desired effect..

not looking for you to write my code, but coded working examples or descriptions as to what could help me achieve my goal, would be helpfull.

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 40px auto;

  .carousel-box-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    transition: none;
    transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);

    .carousel-box {
      width:100px;
      /*width: calc(100% / 4);*/
      padding: 0 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 30px 25px;

      .carousel-subdiv{
        background-color:#a00;
        height:1000px;
        position:absolute;
        top:100px;
      }

      img.carousel-image {
        width:100%;
        height: 125px;
      }
    }
  }

  .carousel-box-wrapper:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="carousel-box-wrapper">
    <div class="carousel-box">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=80%C3%97125&w=80&h=125" />
      <div class="carousel-subdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-box">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=80%C3%97125&w=80&h=125" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-box">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=80%C3%97125&w=80&h=125" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-box">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=80%C3%97125&w=80&h=125" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-box">
      <img class="carousel-image" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=80%C3%97125&w=80&h=125" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: i only have a rough sketchup of what i want so far, but this sort of stopped me in my tracks..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. The code in the question isn't even close to doing what you say you want it to do.

Comment: i am not asking for complete finished code, just to be pointed in the right direction.. i'm currently unable to see a way to do this.

Comment: and i haven't implemented any of the slide functions, all i want to achieve right now is being able to see the "subdiv" while still controlling the overflow at the sides.